# NSURLConnection works perfectly in iOS 4.3 but not in iOS 5 / iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am having some really strange problems with NSURLConnection so I hope you can help me out.

What I am trying to do is download some data from a given URL using NSURLConnection.

I made my own helper class which receives data path, downloads it, and notifies the caller via delegate when the download completes.

The thing works perfectly on my iPhone with iOS 4.3. However, when tested on iOS 5 or iOS6, the `connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data` method is never called and I do not get the desired result.

The class .h file contains:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol NIAsyncDownloaderDelegate
@required
- (void) asyncDownloaderDataDownloadComplete:(NSData *)data withError:(bool) error;
@end

@interface NIAsyncImageDownloader : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
{
    NSURLConnection *theConnection;
    NSMutableData* myData;

    NSURL *downloadURL;

    id delegate;
}

-(id) initWithDataDownloadString:(NSString *) stringAddress;

@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;

@end
```

And the .m file looks like this:

```
#import "NIAsyncDownloader.h"

@implementation NIAsyncImageDownloader

@synthesize delegate;

-(id) initWithDataDownloadString:(NSString *)stringAddress
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        [self loadDataFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringAddress]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadDataFromURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    NSLog(@"Called: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    downloadURL = url;

    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Called: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    NSLog(@"The response is: %@, status code %i, url %@", response.description, ((NSHTTPURLResponse*)response).statusCode, ((NSHTTPURLResponse*)response).URL.description);
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Called: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

    if (myData == nil)
    {
        myData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048];
    }

    [myData appendData:data];
}

//CALLED ON iOS 4.3
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
    //so self data now has the complete image
    NSLog(@"Called: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    [self handleDownloadSuccess];
}

//CALLED ON iOS 5, iOS 6
-(void) connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL
{
    NSLog(@"Called: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    [self handleDownloadSuccess];
}

-(void) handleDownloadSuccess
{    
    NSLog(@"Called: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    [theConnection release];
    theConnection = nil;

    [delegate asyncDownloaderDataDownloadComplete:myData withError:NO];

    [myData release];
    myData = nil;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Called: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    [delegate asyncDownloaderDataDownloadComplete:nil withError:YES];
}

@end
```

Here are some screenshots to show you what I am talking about:

This is what happens when I run the application on iOS5 or iOS6, the request initializes itself, receives a response, and calls `connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL` right away
[image: ios5 ios6]

However, when I run the same application on iOS 4.3, everything works perfectly as you can see from the screenshots below:

[image: ios4.3 1]
[image: iOS4.3 2]

I also noticed that iOS 5 and iOS 6 do not call the same 'finish' method like the iOS 4.3, but I don't think that has has anything to do with my current issue.

And as a final thing, the documentation over here says that the method in question (connection:didReceiveData) is actually deprecated as of iOS 4.3:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

However, another reference states that it is a part of NSURLConnectionDataDelegate protocol and is available since iOS 2:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html

XCode seems to agree that it is deprecated:

[image: xcode]

Just in case anyone wonders how I am using the downloader, it is pretty trivial really:

In .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NIAsyncDownloader.h"

@interface DTViewController : UIViewController <NIAsyncDownloaderDelegate>
{
    NIAsyncImageDownloader *downloader;
}

@end
```

And in .m :

```
#import "DTViewController.h"

@interface DTViewController ()

@end

@implementation DTViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    downloader = [[NIAsyncImageDownloader alloc] initWithDataDownloadString:@"http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/sports/sportsgames/pics/whitedice1.jpg"];
    downloader.delegate = self;
}

-(void) asyncDownloaderDataDownloadComplete:(NSData *)data withError:(bool)error
{
    if (data == nil || error)
    {
        NSLog(@"DOWNLOAD FAILED");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"DOWNLOAD SUCCEEDED");
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

So, summed up, why am I having problems and what to do?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: voted up not just because it's a good question, but because it's a very well written one (problem description, screenshots, what you've tried so far, etc.)

Comment: What do you get if you log the `NSError` in `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`?

Comment: Thanks Bruno :)

@Rich, I get nothing - as you can see there is a NSLog in that delegate method as well, but it is never called because apparently no error occured. Also, as you might have noticed, I am logging 'didReceiveResponse' as well, and the status code is '200' which would indicate everything is OK in both cases

Comment: It would seem that the primary change between iOS 4.3 and 5.0 was that   the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` protocol was introduced and that the methods were *formalized* there. The availability for all of the delegate methods in the protocol reads "Available in iOS 2.0 and later. Available as part of an informal protocol prior to iOS 5.0."

Comment: Yes, I noticed that part too. However, there is something bugging me about that: why does XCode still insist that the method is deprecated, when now it clearly is a part of iOS 5+ library - I've added and removed `<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>` and also cleaned and built the project many times but it's still the same.

Comment: This may be a silly question. But in the handleDownloadSuccess have you tried a save to file or log the data to see if the data is what you expect. And also maybe try and see what the "asyncDownloaderDataDownloadComplete" just before the chaco " if (data == nil || error)..."

Comment: @Mark, I have tried it although there was almost no need for it. If you noticed, `myData` is allocated and initialized in  `connection:didReceiveData` only, and as you can see in the first screenshot that method is never called (in iOS5+ case only, iOS 4.3 calls it as intended which is confirmed by second screenshot). That means I have nothing to check as `myData` is still null when the delegate method `asyncDownloaderDataDownloadComplete` is called or when `handleDownloadSuccess` is called

Comment: Advice. Make your delegate property to be an assign or weak. A retain cycle is created using retain.

Comment: Can you also log the error or check nil data?

Comment: I wonder if the problem is implementing connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL:. There's no need to do that for iOS 5 or 6, you can still use connectionDidFinishLoading:. Have you tried doing it without that method?

Comment: @flexaddicted, thanks for the advice, will do.  

@rdelmar, I can't believe it, it worked! Thank you very much! But I must ask because it makes absolutely no sense to me, why did it cause such problems? When would one need to implement `connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL` then?

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be the problem, but when I set up to do a similar thing I implement the NSURLConnectionDelegate and the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate protocols.  I haven't tested on iOS versions previous to 5, but it has worked in both 5 and 6 for me:

```
@interface NIAsyncImageDownloader : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate> {

}
```

Comment: I tried conforming to every possible combination of protocols among `<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate>` (from all 3 to none, including your suggestion as well), but sadly none of them worked. (I have just tried it again to make sure but unfortunately it didn't help)

Comment: Hrmm.. Wel I'm not exactly sure what you're problem is. But I can share an example of code I'm using that's working for me, maybe it will help you out.  Here's an interface,implementation, and example usage: https://gist.github.com/localhuman/5694156

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I will take a look at it and try to use it

Comment: +1 for `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`. IDK why this protocol isn't listed on official [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `NSURLConnection`...